# Why use standard dhparam values for TLS

Tags: ssl

I understand from a recent publication that there are significant risks with using any of the standard 1024 bit dhparam values.  Sites are being encouraged to use longer dhparam values or generate their own.

Here's my question:

Why would web servers today use *any* standard DH param values?  I created a 4096 bit DH param value on my laptop just now, using openssl dhparam 4096.  It finished in about 40 seconds.

Why isn't that done during web server first run, or configuration?  40 seconds of compute time is not any real burden on a server.  I can understand that an embedded device has a lot more constraints, but a general purpose web server generates a 4096 bit value so fast, is there a reason to ever use a standard value?

And adding to the question...

Why not generate new dh param values on a regular basis, like once a day?  Doing so would greatly reduce the value of a successful attack on any particular set of parameters, and who knows what kind of attacks they may have.

Comment: should be on crypto or security

Answer (score 1):

You think in the right direction. 1024 bit DH Params are two weak nowadays. See the research for the so called LogJam attack (https://weakdh.org/)

Generating a parameter set on a weekly basis is implemented in the mail server dovecot for example. However, generating own params could lead to weak prime numbers. Therefore it is a good idea using well known primes which have been audited many times. For example modp-group 14 (oakley-group-14) from RFC 3526.

Edit:
Did you try generating more of the dhparams consecutively? You should observe a significant grow in amount of time for the generation.

Comment: A *.pem of group 14 can be downloaded here: http://www.eighty-twenty.org/files/oakley-group-2.pem

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do generate my own DH params, using:
`openssl dhparam -2 -outform PEM -out /etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem 4096`
I assume that openssl generates only safe DH params? That command seems to take between 5 minutes and an hour to run.  This server has not much load so why not.